# Google Maps nearby search returning Invalid_Request

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-nearby

I am trying to connect to google maps using the following url and code to fetch nearby places, but I am getting invalid request. What seems to be the issue here?

```
let url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=...&location=49.1804488%2C-122.7851227'
let results = await axios.get(url)
console.log(results.data)
console.log(results.status)
console.log(results.error_message)
console.log(results.info_messages)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby#required-parameters) says that only `location` is required.  That seems to be wrong, adding [`radius`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby#radius) to the query returns a result.

This works:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=49.1804488%2C-122.7851227&radius=1500&key=API_KEY

This doesn't work (returns `"status" : "INVALID_REQUEST"`):

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=49.1804488%2C-122.7851227&key=API_KEY

Answer (score 0):

For me, I accidentally switched the values for `latitude` and `longitude` causing the issue below.

```
{'html_attributions': [], 'results': [], 'status': 'INVALID_REQUEST'}
```

I put the correct values then the request succeeded.